# When invoking subroutines, what is the "size" of a parameter (with rgd to storing it in registers)?

Tags: stack

On the wikipedia entry for "**Call_stack**", under section *Functions of the Call Stack* :: *parameter passing*, it says that:
"Generally if there are only a few **small** parameters, processor registers will be used to pass values..."

What is a "small" parameter? My understanding is that all scalar values (*int* / *float* / *boolean* / *memory address* / etc.) are the same size (number of bits)? A large number of parameters could surely exceed the number of registers. But, what is a **small** parameter?

Comment: Depends on the processor, compiler, instruction set, and register sizes. Small generally means "fits in a register".

Comment: @DaveNewton This is intriguing to me. But, I'm still learning the fundamentals, so I'll have to revisit this topic at a later time. thanks.

Comment: (Moved some followup to an answer for space purposes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the processor, compiler, instruction set, and register sizes.

Small generally means "fits in a register".

For example, on a 32-bit processor an integer might be 32 bits, so it can be put in a register. If the processor has 8 registers, the compiler might allocate 4 of them for params, so if a method has <= 4 integer params, they might be put into registers and not on the stack.

If a processor has floating-point registers, same type of argument. Same with pointers (references) to objects, or any other data type: if the compiler thinks the CPU can spare registers, it'll keep args off the stack. It's possible the compiler could mix-and-match, too, e.g., some on the stack, some in registers.

It also depends on the *nature* of the registers, for example, if a register can be used as an address offset or absolute address, it makes sense to keep references in it if possible. If a register can't be used for a specific data type then it wouldn't be included in the list of possible registers. This is probably less of a concern than it used to be, however.